# Ubuntu 12.04 not Locking Encrypted Hard Drive on Log Out

Tags: 12.04, gnome, external-hdd, luks

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome 3.4. I have two external hard drives. I encrypted both using Ubuntu's Disk Utility. When I use Nautilus to mount them, I'm asked for my decryption password. Regardless of whether I then click "Forget password immediately" or "Remember password until you logout", though, I find that Ubuntu does not lock the drives when I log out. Rather, when I log back in, they're still mounted.

(To be clear, restarting the computer does unmount them so that they require the password on the next log in.)

I'm concerned that these drives are remaining unprotected when I log out without restarting my computer. I would be grateful for help understanding whether this is a bug.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is WAD (Works As Designed), Ubuntu does not unmount disks on logout apart from the encrypted home directory or the private directory (if in use).

You can unmount them by using the eject button on Nautilus or by using the umount command in the terminal, followed by the path the disk was mounted on (you may need to use sudo).

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for that!

If I do select "Remember password forever", where is that password stored? I found http://askubuntu.com/questions/49930/where-are-passwords-stored?rq=1 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/139329/where-are-passwords-saved?rq=1, but am having trouble understanding how secure a saved password for an external hard drive is. I use an encrypted home directory but not full-disk encryption. How is the password safeguarded?

Thank you! I appreciate your help!